# Does Snowflake warehouse base on virtual machine like EC2?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is Snowflake warehouse based on virtual machine like EC2? I mean is every Snowflake warehouse a EC2? It so, it is impossible for warehouse to resume so fast. If it is not, is it based on container or something?

Thanks
Steven

Answer (score 1):

The compute (Virtual Warehouse) layer of Snowflake uses whatever compute is available on the platform the account is set up on. One of the good things about Snowflake is that you don't have to concern yourself with these details, It's probably something like:

- AWS -> EC2
- GCP -> Compute Engine
- Azure -> Virtual Machines

From what I understand, Snowflake maintain a pool of servers. When you shut down your Virtual Warehouse it doesn't mean that your EC2 instance terminate - they just go back into the pool of servers that can be used by other Snowflake customers.

Answer (score 0):

At a high level a Snowflake DWH is composed of three layers

a.) Storage Layer: In AWS this would typically be S3 storage layer

b.) Compute Layer: These are EC2 machines and are used for the Compute and data load

c.) Web Services:  These take care of services like authentication and security

So the compute layer of Snowflake is hosted on EC2.